# Administration console of OpenAM cannot be reached

Tags: jboss, opensso

I have trouble reaching the Administration console of the OpenAM server for a second time after a restart of the JBoss applicationserver on Windows 2008 Server R2 Datacenter.

1. I deploy OpenAM 9.5.2 (the opensso.war file) in the JBoss-4.2.3GA 'deploy' folder of its default profile.
2. I point my Internet Explorer 8 browser to: *my.test.domain.com:8080/opensso*
3. The page appears to create a Default or Custom Configuration for the OpenAM server
4. I successfully complete the wizard for creating a Custom Configuration
5. A pop-up with a 'Proceed to login' link appears after completing the configuration
6. I click this link and I can access the Admin console

Here is the thing:

When I restart JBoss and try to browse to the Admin console URL manually for a second time:

http://my.test.domain.com:8080/opensso/console

It will instead go to the page again to create a Default or Custom Configuration:

http://my.test.domain.com:8080/opensso/config/options.htm

And therefore I cannot access the Admin console anymore.

Note:
I verified that the URL: *my.test.domain.com:8080/opensso/console* is correct by opening
a second tab in IE8 before the restart of JBoss.

Comment: What did you configure as your configuration store?  The internal OpenDS?  Have you checked the logs?

Answer (score 0):

Been looking at doing this myself  - this may provide the solution

https://wikis.forgerock.org/confluence/display/openam/Considerations+when+deploying+on+JBoss+AS+5.1

Comment: You may consider explaining the solution here, posting some snippet code or details about how you do it.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed that will work. I discovered that you can alternatively add in your *run.bat* of JBoss:

```
-Dcom.sun.identity.configuration.directory= your configuration directory
```